# What is the optimal number of threads to create for an IO bound task?

Tags: multithreading, io

I want to download a bunch of tiny MP3 files to merge them together in a big one. I would like to know if, having a CPU with four cores, creating several threads would improve the time needed to download all the files. How can I determine the optimal number of threads to create? Would it help anyway?

Comment: The optimal number of additional threads to create for IO bound tasks is zero. You need asynchronous IO. Threads can only help with CPU bound tasks.

Comment: Download managers allow you to download multiple files concurrently. The number of concurrent downloads has nothing to do with CPU or threading though, it depends on available bandwidth and server-side throttling. You could try to download 100 files at a time, if you have a fast connection and the server allows this

Answer (score 1):

(**EDITED heavily**, see comments for why)

Yes, it will help.  However, the bottleneck is more likely to be the source of the files.  I'm assuming that your data will all be hosted on one source for the rest of this answer.

Someone with more multithreading experience may have some better input on the threads vs. cores, but I'm not sure that it matters.

You're likely going to need to do some experimenting to find the best fit, but it will depend on a lot of factors like bandwidth, server configuration, number of source servers, and number of people using the app at the same time to access these files (assuming it's not just you).

Based on the assumptions I made, I'm going to say 3-6 is going to be the magic number.  Here's my thoughts on why:

- The downloads are very likely to slow down if you have more than that running.
- Because we're talking smaller files, a lot of the overhead will be in starting and stopping the transfer.
- If it were large files, I would've said 3 to start, but because of the overhead mentioned above, you may want to double that.
- As mentioned in the comments, you're threads are going to have a lot of periods of low CPU usage, so the bottleneck of bandwidth and server are much more likely to matter than the number of CPU cores.

Comment: Actually, cores and threads have nothing to do with what is simply concurrent downloads. How many concurrent downloads do you set in your download manager and *why*? It has to do with your network connection, server-side throttling and the number of concurrent connections the *server* allows you to make

Comment: I had that thought, but in absence of details on the other limits, and assuming one server, 3-4 seemed like the correct answer, or at least a place to start. And I couldn't think of a better way to explain my though process.

Comment: why? That's completely arbitrary. A download is mostly idle time. Even if you *blocked* the threads, the CPU would still show minimal usage. If you used an asynchronous API you'd get 0 CPU usage while waiting for the server to respond

Comment: The original 3 to 4 thought came from experience using download managers to download files from a single server and some thoughts on how BitTorrent works, since we're talking small files. But you're right that my answer sounds wrong as written. I'll fix that.

Comment: That should make more sense now.

Comment: I read the answer and the comments, and yes, I think that downloading them asynchronously, say, three by three, I can save time and at the same time I don't suffer the thread creation and management overhead.